# Подождать выполнение анонимной функции в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension

Проблема такая - не удается записать в глобальную переменную данные, чтобы затем их использовать в коде.

```
var proxySetting;

chrome.storage.local.get(['proxySetting'], function (result) {
    proxySetting = JSON.parse(result.proxySetting);
    // при console.log(proxySetting) выводятся данные с хранилища, но позже ошибка будет undefined
    // то есть эта анонимная функция выполняется асинхронно и заканчивается по факту позже конца скрипта
});

document.querySelector('td:nth-child(2)').innerHTML = proxySetting['http_host']; // здесь и ниже как раз undefined
document.querySelector('td:nth-child(3)').innerHTML = proxySetting['http_port']; 
document.querySelector('td:nth-child(4)').innerHTML = proxySetting['auth']['user'];
document.querySelector('td:nth-child(5)').innerHTML = proxySetting['auth']['pass'];
// при console.log(proxySetting) также undefined
```

Вариант ниже, конечно, решает проблему

```
chrome.storage.local.get(['proxySetting'], function (result) {
    var proxySetting = JSON.parse(result.proxySetting);
    document.querySelector('td:nth-child(2)').innerHTML = proxySetting['http_host'];
    document.querySelector('td:nth-child(3)').innerHTML = proxySetting['http_port'];
    document.querySelector('td:nth-child(4)').innerHTML = proxySetting['auth']['user'];
    document.querySelector('td:nth-child(5)').innerHTML = proxySetting['auth']['pass'];
});
```

Но только если я работаю с одним параметром с хранилища и в процессе работы не перезаписываю его, а я это как раз и делаю дальше, в общем вопрос такой - как мне подождать выполнение функции этой, чтобы я мог реализовать функционал не в этой функции получения данных с хранилища, а извне.

P.S. Использование chrome.storage.local/chrome.storage.sync очень желательно при этом сохранить.

P.S.S. Реализованный sleep(2000) не помогает, тут видимо в другом проблема.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте через async await.

```
var p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    chrome.storage.local.get({"proxySettings": true}, function(options){
        resolve(JSON.parse(options.proxySetting));
    })
});

const proxySetting = await p;
console.log(proxySetting);
```